# fix class icontainer minecraft spigot

Tags: java

Can anyone make me this class 1.12.2 compatible? I tried it many times but without success. I would be happy if anyone is so nice. And don't come with learning java or whatever I am new at this learning by doing Example IContainer. this is not in 1.12.2. or `world.notify();`. I do not know what should I add to make this compatible? the owner of this utils is not active anymore so I cant ask.

```
package utils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftWorld;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.IContainer;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.TileEntity;

public class BO2 {

private Arena arena;

public BO2() {
    this.arena = new Arena(this);
}

public Arena getArena() {
    return arena;
}

private static HashSet<Location> blocksForUpdate = new HashSet<>();

public void addBlockUpdate(Location location) {
    blocksForUpdate.add(location);
}

public void startUpdate() {
    new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!blocksForUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.World world = ((CraftWorld) Bukkit.getWorlds().get(0)).getHandle();
                for (Location location : blocksForUpdate) {
                    world.notify(location.getBlockX(), location.getBlockY(), location.getBlockZ());
                }
                blocksForUpdate.clear();
            }
        }
    }.runTaskTimer(Utils.getPlugin(Utils.class), 1, 1);
}

/* Spawn BO2 */

public List<Block> spawn(Location location, File file) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BufferedReader reader;
    ArrayList<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.contains(",") || !line.contains(":")) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            String[] coordinates = parts[0].split(",");
            String[] blockData = parts[1].split("\\.");

            setBlockFast(location.getWorld(), location.getBlockX() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[0]), location.getBlockY() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[2]), location.getBlockZ() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[1]), Integer.valueOf(blockData[0]), blockData.length > 1 ? Byte.valueOf(blockData[1]) : 0);
            blocks.add(location.getWorld().getBlockAt(location.getBlockX() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[0]), location.getBlockY() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[2]), location.getBlockZ() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[1])));
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("BO2 spawnada em " + (time - System.currentTimeMillis()) + "ms");
    return blocks;
}

/* Load BO2 file */

public List<FutureBlock> load(Location location, File file) {
    BufferedReader reader;
    ArrayList<FutureBlock> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.contains(",") || !line.contains(":")) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            String[] coordinates = parts[0].split(",");
            String[] blockData = parts[1].split("\\.");
            blocks.add(new FutureBlock(location.clone().add(Integer.valueOf(coordinates[0]), Integer.valueOf(coordinates[2]), Integer.valueOf(coordinates[1])), Integer.valueOf(blockData[0]), blockData.length > 1 ? Byte.valueOf(blockData[1]) : 0));
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return blocks;
}

/* Set methods */

public boolean setBlockFast(World world, int x, int y, int z, int blockId, byte data) {
    if (y >= 255 || y < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.World w = ((CraftWorld) world).getHandle();
    net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.Chunk chunk = w.getChunkAt(x >> 4, z >> 4);
    boolean b = data(chunk, x & 0x0f, y, z & 0x0f, net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.Block.getById(blockId), data);
    addBlockUpdate(new Location(Bukkit.getWorlds().get(0), x, y, z));
    return b;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean setBlockFast(Location location, Material material, byte data) {
    return setBlockFast(location.getWorld(), location.getBlockX(), location.getBlockY(), location.getBlockZ(), material.getId(), data);
}

private boolean data(net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.Chunk that, int i, int j, int k, net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.Block block, int l) {
    int i1 = k << 4 | i;

    if (j >= that.b[i1] - 1) {
        that.b[i1] = -999;
    }

    int j1 = that.heightMap[i1];
    net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.Block block1 = that.getType(i, j, k);
    int k1 = that.getData(i, j, k);

    if (block1 == block && k1 == l) {
        return false;
    } else {
        boolean flag = false;
        net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ChunkSection chunksection = that.getSections()[j >> 4];

        if (chunksection == null) {
            if (block == net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.Blocks.AIR) {
                return false;
            }

            chunksection = that.getSections()[j >> 4] = new net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ChunkSection(j >> 4 << 4, !that.world.worldProvider.g);
            flag = j >= j1;
        }

        int l1 = that.locX * 16 + i;
        int i2 = that.locZ * 16 + k;

        if (!that.world.isStatic) {
            block1.f(that.world, l1, j, i2, k1);
        }
        if (!(block1 instanceof IContainer)) {
            chunksection.setTypeId(i, j & 15, k, block);
        }
        if (!that.world.isStatic) {
            block1.remove(that.world, l1, j, i2, block1, k1);
        } else if (block1 instanceof IContainer && block1 != block) {
            that.world.p(l1, j, i2);
        }
        if (block1 instanceof IContainer) {
            chunksection.setTypeId(i, j & 15, k, block);
        }
        if (chunksection.getTypeId(i, j & 15, k) != block) {
            return false;
        } else {
            chunksection.setData(i, j & 15, k, l);
            if (flag) {
                that.initLighting();
            }
            TileEntity tileentity;

            if (block1 instanceof IContainer) {
                tileentity = that.e(i, j, k);
                if (tileentity != null) {
                    tileentity.u();
                }
            }
            if (!that.world.isStatic && (!that.world.captureBlockStates || (block instanceof net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.BlockContainer))) {
                block.onPlace(that.world, l1, j, i2);
            }

            if (block instanceof IContainer) {
                if (that.getType(i, j, k) != block) {
                    return false;
                }
                tileentity = that.e(i, j, k);
                if (tileentity == null) {
                    tileentity = ((IContainer) block).a(that.world, l);
                    that.world.setTileEntity(l1, j, i2, tileentity);
                }

                if (tileentity != null) {
                    tileentity.u();
                }
            }

            that.n = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

/* FutureBlock Utils */

public class FutureBlock {
    private Location location;
    private int id;
    private byte data;

    public FutureBlock(Location location, int id, byte data) {
        this.location = location;
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public byte getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void place() {
        location.getBlock().setTypeIdAndData(id, data, true);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, just to elaborate on what @alfasin said, stack overflow is not meant for developers to ask for other people to do work for them. Stack overflow is meant more for developers who are trying to solve a problem for themselves and could use help to point them in the right direction.

Comment: i have i problem idk what arguments should i add to world.notify. to dont get a error. idk how to make this spigot 1.12.2 compatible. and idk what i should replace IContainer